Unable to use springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui with non Spring Boot project
I am using Spring 6 in my application without Spring Boot. I am trying to use Springdoc to document the REST APIs available in my application. For this purpose, I have used springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui.jar as mentioned in the Springdoc documentation. I have added all the dependent jars and also made the necessary configurations.
Even then when I try to load http://localhost:<port>/swagger-ui.html, I am getting a 404 Page Not Found error. I am not getting any more information other than this error.
